# Microsoft Access APIs?

Tags: rest, ms-access, microsoft-graph-api, ms-access-2016

I've been digging through Microsoft's API pages (both the REST APIs and the Graph APIs) - but I'm having a hard time finding out if there is any way to access Microsoft Access through an API.

I'd like to be able to make an API call to get like the list of rows in a particular table or query for the list of tables altogether - or, on the flip side, add a row to an existing table. (Edit: I'd like to do this via REST calls and allow users to connect accounts so that many different people could access these things on their own). Does anyone know if this is possible? I'd super appreciate any links to any API docs or examples y'all have ^.^

For reference, I've been looking primarily at these two places:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/access-home

Comment: You're looking for ADO.

Comment: @KenWhite - Thanks for the suggestion! Unless I'm misreading something, it looks like ADO is more about accessing SQL Server rather than Microsoft Access. Furthermore, it looks like ADO is designed for people wanting to interact with their data via code. I'm more looking to see if there are like public APIs people can use to do said things. For instance, it would be swell if there was a "ListTables" API that I could hit with an access token and get a list of tables for a particular user.

I've gone ahead and modified my question a bit to hopefully be more clear but thanks again for the tip!

Comment: ADO is the generic API for accessing data in Windows, whether it's SQL Server or Access or any other database that supports ADO.  Read more in the documentation - you've misunderstood what you've read. ADO works perfectly well with Access.

Comment: Industry standard databases like Oracle or even SQL server all have API's that your system can use. So SQL server or Excel or even PowerPoint or Access all have a API (COM based). You can a REST URL (or SOAP) to pull data from say SQL server or Oracle or PowerPoint. Now SQL server, or notepad or Access certainly does not have a REST API built in, but any web server certainly can return data from such system like SQL server. You the developer will have to provide that REST URL or web service call. So Access, PowerPoint or SQL server are not different in this regards. You have to create that URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access doesn't provide any functionality to directly access the data from a HTTP endpoint (REST API). It can only function as a database(backend) in this scenario and you would need to look into other solutions to get the data from the database and provide it from a HTTP endpoint (REST API).

If you're looking to use Microsoft technologies for this solution, then you can look into ASP.NET Core to provide the Web API functionality.

You'll need the Access Data Provider to be able to access data in a MS Access database, which as far as I know runs only on a Windows OS.